# OMXPLAYER black screen after video for 1 second

Tags: raspbian

Can you prevent OMXPLAYER from blacking out the entire screen for 1 second after each video?

Comment: Actually issue was resolved, see thread at github https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/133#issuecomment-14932120

Comment: You can edit /usr/local/omxplayer and remove everything since line 13 (GREP=which grep)

Answer (score 1):

The script is quite simple

```
omxplayer $1
xrefresh
```

Start it with

```
sh script.sh video.mp4
```

Else, you can update omxplayer, it has been resolved in recent version.

Answer (score -1):

use `xrefresh` after the command or write a little script as I did ;-)

Comment: Would you care to share your little script? It might be worthy of an up vote then.

Comment: Agree with @Impulss , sharing the script and how you use it will improve the quality of answers on this site, and potentially help other users with the same issue.